# AngularJs:loading angular page from normal Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a situation here. I have used angularJS for my application and also using $resource for service call. Now i want to implement a new functionality in this. In this i need to show a checkbox for which i have a code in index.html and i need to load the services conditionally. but i am not specifying ng-app in this. I want my application to behave as angular from the second page which i am redirecting from index. Is it possible to do? If yes can anyone help me please?

Here is the sample code which i have tried but am stuck:

Index.html

```
<body>
        <div>
            <table style="margin-left:40%">
                <td style="width:62%">
                    <label id="sampleEnv" style="margin-top:10%">First Login</label>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <div class="onoffswitch">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
                            <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
                                <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
                                <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
                            </label>
                            </div>
                </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="checkVal()">
                </div>

<script>
function onclick(){
alert(document.getElementById("myonoffswitch").checked);
location.href="views/login.html";
}
</script>
</body>
```

Login.html

```
<html ng-app="sampleApp">
    <head>       
    </head>
<body ng-controller="sampleController">
<form name="sampleForm"  ng-submit="authenticate()" novalidate>
        <div>
            <table align="center">
                    <tr>
                        <td>ID</td>
                        <td> <input name="sampleId" type="text" maxlength="9" ng-model="sampleIdModel" integer/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input type="password" name="password" ng-model="password" passwordmin /></td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

App.js

```
var app = angular.module("sampleApp", ["sampleService"]);
```

After clicking on the submit button on index page, login page comes but fully distorted. After debugging in chrome, i found that login.html doesn't have any support from any other controller or js which was loaded in index.html .

Any help will be very useful.
Thanks in advance.